# AroundInvoke and checked exceptions

Tags: java, exception, ejb

I have a question about AroundInvoke annotation. Let's say I have a bean with method a, which is enhanced with method with annotation AroundInvoke in some Interceptor. Method a does not have any exceptions in signature, while the 'enhancing' method can throw some checked exception. There is no compilation error, but what happens on runtime, when the situation occurs (as in the @AroundInvoke method throws this checked exception)? Does it get converted to a some runtime exception?

Answer (score 1):

The [interceptor 1.2 specification](https://java.net/downloads/interceptors-spec/interceptor-1-2-mrel.pdf) (latest as of this post) does not specify behavior for this scenario, so the behavior will be product-specific.  I would not recommend relying on that behavior unless the product documents that behavior and you're ok with product-specific dependencies.  I suspect most implementations will throw an unchecked exception of some kind (most likely EJBException or UndeclaredThrowableException).  I know WebSphere Application Server throws EJBException.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why an interceptor's at aroundinvoke is marked to throw a checked exception, is because we truly do not know what the intercepted method can throw, whether a checked or unchecked exception.
Consider the scenario where the user has defined an `ApplicationException` which is thrown by the intercepted method, then the interceptor, should, in normal cases propagate this exception to the client.

In rare circumstances should an intercepting method throw an exception, unless its doing some cross-cutting logic (which is not meant for an interceptor though).

However, if an exception is thrown, either by the interceptor or the intercepted method, and the exception is not annotated `ApplicationException` The ejb runtime must wrap it into an `EJBException`  and rethrows it as such. If it is an `ApplicationException` the ejb container must not wrap into `EjBException` and must propagate it to the client as is.