# AroundInvoke: Curious name?

Tags: java, cdi, interceptor

Request more information on this interceptor annotation. Why is the interceptor annotation called @AroundInvoke and not @BeforeInvoke?

Can I for example invoke an access verification before an action API? What is the guarantee that the Access Verification is completed before the method is actually invoked? Is there something that the VM or the CDI implementation do that does not prevent the actual invocation but execute this interceptor in parallel?

If I were using the [Google Guice AOP Method Interceptors](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP), I am assured that the Access Verification failure will determine whether or not the method invocation BEGINS. How can I assure myself of a similar behavior from the jakarta CDI?

Have not been able to find this information in the spec

A related question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920433/aroundinvoke-and-checked-exceptions). But the exact questions above remain unanswered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@AroundInvoke` is called that because it can act **both** before **and** after the actually invoked method. Look at [the documentation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/interceptors/2.0/apidocs/jakarta/interceptor/aroundinvoke) and its sample:

> ```
> @AroundInvoke
> public Object intercept(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception { ... }
> ```

In that method you can call `ctx.proceed()` to call the target method (or any other interceptors). When you do stuff **before** that call then you act *before* the method and anything you do **after** that call happens *after* the method is called. Therefore it's "around" the method.

Sample:

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object intercept(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
   log.info("We're about to do the thing!");
   Object result = ctx.proceed();
   log.info("We did the thing!");
   return result;
}
```

Comment: This sentence is somewhat loaded: "Defines an interceptor method that interposes on business methods". Thanks for making the meaning clearer.